# Is 'I would rather...' without an infinitive immediately following it correct?

Tags: infinitives, sentence-patterns

Consider:

> I would rather the walls remain painted in a neutral tint.

Is this proper use of 'I would rather..', without an infinitive immediately following it?

**EDIT** [This](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv107.shtml) suggests that 'I would rather ...' is either followed by an infinitive or by an object (?) + past tense if you would want to include other people. But not the use I propose.

Comment: This is a good example of a [misleading grammatical title](grammatical). This sentence has an infinitive in it, but it's normally treated as if it were a tensed verb in the "subjunctive", which of course is not correct.

Comment: @TimLymington - that question deals with the (non-grammatical) construction "I rather" creeping into use as a substitute for "I would rather".  Not the same question at all.

Comment: I can't figure out what *"without an infinitive"* is supposed to mean here. This question certainly isn't a dup as indicated, because OP here *does* have a verb in "would". The example is unremarkable, and I think the question is General Reference.

Comment: Without an infinitive **immediately following it**.

Comment: @mvexel: I'd rather you'd said that in the question. What makes you think there's anything odd about following *rather* with a [pro]noun?

Comment: Fair enough - I changed the title to better reflect what the question states.

Comment: Again, it's not a matter of what follows what. It's a matter of what happens to the clause. If it's a _that_-clause, or if it's a [B-configuration infinitive](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), it's gonna have a subject between _would rather_ and the (infinitive) verb in the complement.

Comment: I think what John Lawler is saying is that "remain" *is* an "infinitive", notwithstanding the fact that some people would call it "subjunctive". But are you seriously saying you've never heard anyone say anything like *"I'd rather **you** didn't do that"*? I still can't figure out what you see as the problem here.

Comment: BTW, the link got messed up in my comment above. It should point to [this meta answer](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2802/15299), specifically my last comment below it.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that _rather_ is not normally a predicate.

Comment: I had heard about the usage, 'I would rather...', but never had the courage to use it. For me it sounds incomplete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sentence is a proper use of *would rather*. **And** it contains an infinitive.

*Would rather* is an idiomatic predicate that means *prefer,* and has many of the same syntactic affordances and restrictions as *prefer*, although *would rather* doesn't use the infinitive complementizer *to*, while *prefer* requires it. Both are negative triggers and can trigger [NPIs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), for instance,

- *I would rather do **anything** else.*
- *I prefer to do **anything** else.*

In addition, both predicates can take a *that*-clause complement with an **untensed** verb:

- *I would rather (that) he **sit** down immediately.*
- *I prefer (that) he **sit** down immediately.*
- **I would rather that he sits down immediately.*
- **I prefer that he sits down immediately.*

The sentence in question is simply an untensed (i.e, infinitive) verb form in such a complement clause, with the *that* complementizer deleted:

- *I would rather (that) [the walls remain painted in a neutral tint]*.

Note that if you use a form of *be* instead of *remain*, you get the infinitive form *be*:

- *I would rather (that) [the walls **be** painted in a neutral tint]*.
- **I would rather (that) [the walls are painted in a neutral tint]*.

There are a lot more infinitives around than one might suspect from Miss Fidditch's class.

Comment: Given that "I would rather" indicates a wish, the subjunctive is not inappropriate, surely? How do you tell the difference between "be" as untensed indicative and "be" as subjunctive, since the forms are the same?

Comment: You don't. Because if you can't tell the difference, the difference isn't there. They're both the same form. They just have a number of different uses, is all. Like _the_ or _of_ or _that_ or _which_ or _to._ "The subjunctive" is like phlogiston; an early attempt at explanation that didn't turn out to work.

Comment: Except that the subjunctive does exist in constructions like "If I were...", so it might just as well exist here too. That is, once "that" is introduced, the mood changes. "He sit" and "the walls be" (or even "the walls were") are subjunctive constructions. I guess I disagree that a subject should have an infinitive indicative verb: perhaps I'm just reactionary.

Comment: There aren't many other choices in English. Except for _be_, there's only 5 verb forms available: Infinitive, 3SgPres, Past, PastPart, PresPart. That's **it**. Which one is the subjunctive? In German or French or Spanish, which **do** have subjunctive, there are several forms for every verb that are **always** subjunctive. That's many thousand subjunctive verbs; English doesn't have a single one.

Comment: This is hardly “untensed”: **I would rather it *were* otherwise.** Smells awfully past subjunctive to me.

Comment: It's a past tense verb form, all right. If you want to call it subjunctive, you're adding nothing to the term, because nothing is added to the form.

Comment: The fact that the form doesn't change doesn't mean the word is not different. Take the verb "to read" for example and parse "You read it" (pronunciation differs, but form doesn't). I lament the minimisation of the language. [And I'm now going on holiday, so I shall be quiet]

Comment: @Andrew Leach ‘. . .  in English, “past subjunctive” forms are indistinguishable from past tense forms. We will therefore say that English does not have a past subjunctive verb inflection . . . The reason is that we cannot contrast a clause containing a “past subjunctive verb” with a clause containing a past tense form of the verb’. (‘Oxford Modern English Grammar’ by Bas Aarts)

Comment: @Andrew Leach: As for the ‘were-subjunctive’, Huddlelston and Pullum don’t call it a subjunctive at all, using ‘irrealis’ instead. ‘Traditional grammar calls our “irrealis” a “past subjunctive” . . . But there are no grounds for analysing this “were” as a past tense counterpart of the “be” that we find in constructions like “It’s vital that he be kind to her”.’

Comment: @AndrewLeach, Re: _read_. Pronunciation ***is*** form. /ɪfayraytɪŋɡlɪʃðɪswe/, it's still English; spelling is mere technology, not language. Don't confuse the car with the driver.

Comment: The trouble with using a bare infinitive is that it does not spring to the tongue of most speakers. I would be happy with 'I would rather the walls remained painted...' A slight stylistic concern is that the sentence contains two similar consecutive past forms.

Comment: Since /dp/ is a hard consonant cluster to pronounce, probably most English speakers intending to say 'I would rather the walls remained painted...' would wind up saying [ri'mẽ:'pʰẽɾəd], no matter what their intention. How you want to spell that is your business.

Comment: @John Lawler, What about 'I'd rather he sat down immediately'?

Answer (score 1):

Those so-called untensed verbs that - according to what is written above - could be admitted, are actually subjunctives. Their use in English is very rare and fading away but they're still subjonctives. The confusion is easy at first sight, because they keep the infinitive form whatever or whoever is the subject : I be, you be, he be, we be, you all be, they be.

Comment: Please add references to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the word rather as a verb meaning *prefer* is sometimes called *verbal rather*. The use you describe is one of a number of well-attested uses of verbal rather. There are actually two structures that your sentence might have:

1. I would rather they remain painted...
2. I would rather (that) they remain painted…

There are a number of other uses of verbal rather that are quite widespread throughout North American English. However, these uses vary in interesting ways across speakers and dialects. For more information, see the discussion of this phenomenon at the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project website, on our page for Verbal rather: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/verbal-rather.