# Can you help me identify the adverb?

Tags: adverbs

> The railway station is far away.

Where is the adverb here, and what does it modify? My answer was "away", but I am not quite sure if it's correct.

I am also confused by

> I would rather wait

as i don't know what "rather" modifies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What part of speech does “here” have in “I am here”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058/what-part-of-speech-does-here-have-in-i-am-here) (Q1). And 
[... would rather...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73891/is-i-would-rather-without-an-infinitive-immediately-following-it-correct) for Q2. // Essentially, more modern treatments have a different idea about what constitutes an adverb than does traditional grammar.

Comment: @tchrist Much better fit.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence:

> The railway station is far away.

"far" is an adverb, and so is "away".

We can consider that "far away" is an adverbial where "far" quantifies "away" (compare with "X kilometers/miles away").

"far" is an adjective when it precedes a noun, as in "Far East".